# Python Selenium - find table elements <td> based on a string and click the associatet radio button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select a radiobutton, based on his  text value.

So on this [site](http://nvv31.webqms.de/nvv/kunden/)
i skip the first page with this code (because its a frame)

```
driver.switch_to_frame(0)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("bedin")
elem.click()
clickWeiter()
```

After that i want to click a radiobutton, which has a certain text, for example 'Bus'

My Problem is, that the actual radio button is in a  tag

```
<input type="radio" name="mittel" value="2" onclick="zweiSelect4('neu',2);document.form1.linie.disabled=false;">
```

but the readable text 'Bus' is in a td tag

```
<td height="36" align="left" class="Stil1"><input type="radio" name="mittel" value="2" onclick="zweiSelect4('neu',2);document.form1.linie.disabled=false;">Bus </td>
```

so far i managed to click the radio button based on his value, not text

```
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='2']").click
```

or i managed to get the text, but couldnt click it

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
for i in list:
    searchval =("Bus")
if searchval in str(i.text):
    print(" BULLSEYE" , i.text)
    i.click()
```

my goal is to have a function which i pass the desired text (Sonstiges, Bus,etc) and then click the element.

Comment: your `if searchval in str(i.text):` code block is indented wrongly. Is that wrong formatting or is thaty your acual code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the website `http://nvv31.webqms.de/nvv/kunden/` to click any of the radio buttons associated with text as **Regionalzug**, **Tram** or **Bus** you can write a function which will take the string as an argument as follows:

```
def click_me(myString):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='Stil1']//td[contains(.,'" + myString + "')]/input[@name='mittel']").click()
```

Now you can call the function `click_me()` with any of the relevant text as follows:

```
click_me("Regionalzug")
click_me("Tram")
click_me("Bus")
click_me("AnrufSammelTaxi")
```

Comment: Your Code works flawlessly. It doenst matter if the argument is Regionalzug or Haltestelle or Bus or Sonstiges or even partial match like zug. Everything works perfectly. EDIT: `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` should be `element` , then it works

Comment: I am sitting at a problem close to this one. Could you please explain what: /input[@name='mittel']"  does?

Comment: @exec85 `/input[@name='mittel']` will locate the immediate child/descendant of its parent/ancestor of type `input` having `name` attribute set as `mittel`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **xpath** :

```
//td[contains(text(),'Bus')]/input
```

in code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Bus')]/input").click()
```

as you have mentioned, that you would like to have a method , for that you can try :

```
visible = "Bus"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'"+visible+"')]/input").click()
```

Method :

```
def myfunc(visible):
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'"+visible+"')]/input").click()
```

Then you can call this method with your required text.

Hope this will help.

**UPDATE :**

Those are text nodes, you can try something like :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver   = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,40)

driver.get("http://nvv31.webqms.de/nvv/kunden/")

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//frame[@src='kundengarantie.php']"))
driver.find_element_by_name('bedin').click()
continue_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('weiter')
continue_link.click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//frame[@src='kundengarantie.php']"))

all_text = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td.Stil1 input") 

text_node = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent;", all_text[1])

text_node_trim = text_node.strip()

print(text_node_trim)


def myfunc(visible):
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(.,'"+text_node_trim+"')]/input").click()  

myfunc("Haltestelle / Bahnhof")
```

Comment: Thank youcruisepandey and DebanjanB. Both your solutions work, but only for one Word like Bus, Regionalzug. i cant make "Haltestelle / Bahnhof" and "Tram / RegioTram" as an function argument to work

NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //td[contains(text(),'Tram')]/input

Comment: messed the exception result up. here is the result for Tram / RegioTram as an argument: NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //td[contains(text(),'Tram / RegioTram')]/input

Comment: i ran your code, only changed the value driver = webdriver.Firefox(). Now it always returns Haltestelle / Bahnhof, regardless of the argument in myfunc. Probadly because the argument visible is nowhere in the function myfunc. You mentioned that some radiobuttons are text nodes. so some of the six buttons are different then the other? what im trying to say is, is this site so messed up it would be a pain to automate with selenium? if its to hard, i will glady use something like:
`complain = ("3") # bus
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='%s']" % complain).click()`

Comment: You will have to make myfun as a method which will take two argument 1. First is text of radio button 2. Number of radio button , I mean index number. give me some time I will update my answer as soon as possible.